# Prettify not working in my django ap

Tags: django, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to output content using prettify but it comes out as if I'm not even using it. This is my view.py

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def sewp(request):
r = requests.get("http://www.vladtv.com/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

content = soup.prettify()

ella = "ella"
context = {
    "content": content,
    "ella": ella,
}
return render(request, "posts/display_soup.html", context)
```

heres my template

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
<p>ll</p>
<p>{{ ella  }}</p>
<p>{{ content }}</p>
```

I don't get any errors it just is not prettyfied

if I print it it's prettyfied in the terminal. How can I prettyfy it's out put in my template. also

```
soup.title
```

returns this in the template []

Comment: Do you mean it to actually be rendered too - what if you use `<p>{{ content|safe }}</p>`?..

Comment: For some reason I cannot reproduce the problem - I see the prettified html inside the `p` tag. Could you please add your current output to the question?..thanks.

Comment: @if I use {{ content|safe }} I return the actual site, not just raw html

Comment: @losee you need raw html to be shown in your template instead of the page (vladtv.com)?

Comment: @doniyor yes. I'm just learning how to use B.S. I want to be able to see what see it the way it is displayed in the terminal.

Comment: Try using `<pre>` instead of `<p`> tag.

Comment: @xyres Pre tag split it up but by adding comas and made it more readable but it didnt put each one on a new line. So I have to scroll all the way to the right to see all the code